# Validating that associated objects have the same parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm creating kind of triangular structure like this:

```rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :departments
  has_many :employees
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :department # optional, employee can belong only to a company
end
```

Now, when creating Employee, what's the best way to make sure that it's possible to assign only departments that belong to the same company as the employee I'm creating?

`company_id` is automatically assigned from nested resource route and `department_id` is from params. I guess I could create a custom method that would validate this, but I was wondering if there's some kind of out of the box way (eg. using only associations) to do this.

So for example I'd like to avoid something like this:

```
CompA ---- DepA
 \
  \_ !EmpA! _
             \
CompB ---- DepB ---- EmpC
  \___________________/
   \        
    \_______ EmpD
```

Comment: how department is belongs_to department?

Comment: Sorry it's a typo, it belongs to a company. Fixed it

Comment: You have 2 types Employees(Not sure this is required). why you need `company_id` in `Employee` table, it will be associated through 'Department`. Isn't it?

Comment: In the first code sample you can notice that `department_id` is optional for `employee`, `employee` can belong straight to the `company` without `department` assigned. So it can't have only `department` association.